# MSDOS таблица разделов

Tags: dos

Читаю вот эту ссылку по MSDOS:

https://www.frolov-lib.ru/books/bsp/v19/ch2_1.html

хотел уточнить. То есть таблица разделов находится в MBR (по смещению 1BEh от начала MBR), у таблицы разделов может быть не более 4х записей по 16 байт каждая, т.е. один основной раздел и три расширенных - всего 4ре, в каждом расширенном разделе можно создать любое количество логических дисков. Я прав или кто может поправить?

Comment: *т.е. один основной раздел и три расширенных - всего 4ре* Не так. Либо до 4 основных, либо до 3 основных и 1 расширенный. В расширенном - формально неограниченное количество логических томов. Формально можно создать 2 или 3 расширенных - но MS DOS не умеет работать с более чем 1 расширенным разделом.